# initialize a pandas empty dataframe with data type string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a Dataframe with given number of rows and columns, and want to initialize every element with data type string.

When I'm using :

```
pd.DataFrame(np.empty((3, 4)), dtype = "S100")
```

It gives an empty dataframe but the data type is binary.

Is there any other dtype parameter which gives me data type as str.

Comment: `dtype = str` ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the type of the empty array:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.empty((3, 4), dtype = np.str))
```